# How to update a column using another column's multiple data?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update, sql-merge

## test1

```
t1  t2

1
```

## test2

```
x

1

2

3

upto 20
```

so I want all the `x` values copy into `t2`.
How should I?

More detailed :

> There r 2 tables 'test1' , 'test2'. ' test1 ' having 2 columns i.e '
>   t1 ' , ' t2 ' and ' test2 ' having 1 column i.e ' x '. so I need to
>   copy test2.x column values to test1.t2 column. test1.t1 - 1, test1.t2
>   - null, test2.x - 1,2,3,4 ..... 20

Comment: your question is not clear to me

Comment: Downvote for the vagueness of the question. Please consider rewording this...

Comment: are the values of `test1.t1` 1,2,3 ... 20, also ..?

Comment: There r 2 tables 'test1' , 'test2'. ' test1 ' having 2 columns i.e ' t1 ' , ' t2 ' and ' test2 ' having 1 column i.e ' x '. so I need to copy test2.x column values to test1.t2 column. test1.t1 - 1, test1.t2 - null, test2.x - 1,2,3,4 ..... 20, Hope now u got it.

Answer (score 2):

Question text is not clear, as much as i understand, you have values for t1 column of test1 table as `1,2,3 ... 20`, also, and if you'd like to copy all from test2.x, you may use :

```
update test1 t1
   set t1.t2 = ( select t2.x
                   from test2 t2
                  where t2.x = t1.t1 );
```

but, actually there's no need of another table(`table2`)

```
update test1 t1 set t1.t2 = t1.t2;
```

With respect to your last edit, you need a `merge` statement :

```
merge into test1 a
  using test2 b
    on (nvl(a.t1,0) = nvl(b.x,0))
  when matched then
    update set a.t2 = nvl(b.x,0)
  when not matched then
    insert(t2)
    values(nvl(b.x,0));
```

and then you can get the following :

```
select * from test1 order by t2;

T1  T2
--  --------------------------------------------------
1   1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    10
    .
    .
    .
    20
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/359a8/22)

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, but I have tried this, it will update only one row of the test1 table, I want 1,2,3 ..... 20 to be there in the test1.t2 column. Hope u understand my question. I need test2.x values copy to test1.t2 column.

Comment: @Ranjan you're welcome, friend. I've edited both your question(according to your comment), and my answer.

Comment: thank you @Barbaros Ozhan, I am appreciating ur answer, but what if I need the values should exactly like test2.x, Not side by side, it should by row by row. Like ur 1st answer. it was ok, but it only updates 1 row, and I need all the 20 rows in 'test1' table.

Comment: update (select * from test1,test2)
set t2=x; I got the error in this query.(ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table.)

Comment: @Ranjan I edited the answer so that you can see the results in the Demo.

Comment: Ozhan, Plz see the above, I want to get this as a result.

Comment: Ozhan, Thank you so much friend, now I got it.